# How to create dataset in python with creation options like in ogr2ogr with -dsco options

Tags: python, gdal, dxf, feature-dataset

In ogr2ogr there is dsco option (data source creation option).
e.g. `ogr2ogr -f DXF  -dsco trailer=trailer_buildings.dxf -dsco header=header_buildings.dxf out.dxf test_buldings_shp.shp`. It works well, but how can I use the same dsco options in Python?

```
from osgeo import ogr,gdal
import os,sys

def create_dxf(dxf_out_path):   
    header_path = u'c:\header.dxf'
    trailer_path = u'c:\trailer.dxf'
    dxf_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('DXF')
    dsco = {'HEADER':header_path,'TRAILER':trailer_path}
    dxf_ds = dxf_driver.CreateDataSource(dxf_out_path,**dsco)
    gdal.SetConfigOption('DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS', 'TRUE')
```

This code throws an error: ***TypeError: Driver_CreateDataSource() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)***

If I keep only one argument in dsco dictionary I get the following error:
***TypeError: 'header' is an invalid keyword argument for this function***. I've tried UPPER and *lower* cases but nothing helps. [Documentation](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Driver-class.html#CreateDataSource) tells to watch supported options for each format [here](http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html). And I clearly see that in DXF format there are HEADER and TRAILER creation option. But Python errors tells me vise versa things. I think option name in ogr2ogr utility doesn't correspond to option name in python gdal library, and if it so, where i can find documentation with full list of options for each vector format and for each language and utility? (e.g. ogr2ogr: `-dsco HEADER='dxf_path.dxf'`; python: `kwargs = {'dxf_header':'dxf_path.dxf'}`, etc...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The options value is a list, not a dict, and the elements are key value pairs. Try:

```
co = ["HEADER=" + header_path, "TRAILER=" + trailer_path]
dxf_ds = dxf_driver.CreateDataSource(dxf_out_path, options=co)
```

I can't say dictionaries don't work, buy I don't recall seeing them in my experience. The python bindings closely follow the standard GDAL API.

Comment: thank you for reply. It works. I was confused when read in documentation that options should to be PAIRS of key-value, that's why i decided to use _dictionary_ instead of _list_, where one _string_ is pair splited by =

Comment: Agreed, it can be confusing, especially for experienced python folks