# Is there any way to connect features (entities) of dxf to database in python?

Tags: python, gdal, database, dxf, odbc

I'm using *gdal, ezdxf, sqlite* python packages and sqlite ODBC driver. They work fine, and in AutoCAD I can easily manually connect to my dbase.sqlite (read only)  using *_DBCONFIGURE* and *_DBCONNECT* commands. Then, in AutoCAD, I  manually make a connection template like *table1Connection1* and select the primary key (in my case *GID*) from dbase. Then I save an empty DXF with dbconection and use it as *header* and *trailer* parameters in gdal to create a new [dataset](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192277/how-to-create-dataset-in-python-with-creation-options-like-in-ogr2ogr-with-dsco). Now using gdal, sqlite and\or ezdxf I want to convert to GIS files (mapinfo, shapefile, Filegdb etc.) with TABLE OF ATTRIBUTE. I've made a couple of *hand-made* connections to my dabse.sqlite in AutoCAD and saved it as *sqlite_connected.dxf* and then ran the following code:

```
#! c:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\python.exe
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- import ezdxf import os

ezdxf.options.debug


def test_dxf(source_drawing):
    source_drawing = ezdxf.readfile_as_utf8(old_dxf, errors='strict')
    source_drawing.encoding = 'utf-8'
    modelspace = source_drawing.modelspace()

    for element in modelspace:
        print element.dxftype()
        print 'Valid_tag_list'
        print  element.valid_dxf_attrib_names()
        handle = element.dxf.handle
        tags = source_drawing.entitydb[handle]
        for tag in tags:
            print tag

if __name__ == '__main__':
    old_dxf = os.path.abspath('../../data/sqlite_connected.dxf')       
    test_dxf(old_dxf)
```

*prints* shows the following:

```
ELLIPSE
Valid_tag_list
'[u'shadow_mode', u'layer', u'handle', u'linetype', u'color', u'start_param', u'major_axis', u'end_param', u'true_color', u'ltscale', u'color_name', u'transparency', u'owner', u'ratio', u'extrusion', u'invisible', u'paperspace', u'center']
DXFTag(code=0, value=u'ELLIPSE')
DXFTag(code=5, value=u'246')
DXFTag(code=330, value=u'1F')
DXFTag(code=100, value=u'AcDbEntity')
DXFTag(code=8, value=u'0')
DXFTag(code=62, value=3)
DXFTag(code=100, value=u'AcDbEllipse')
DXFTag(code=10, value=(-64.72147324890284, 1396.049664909873, 0.0))
DXFTag(code=11, value=(-432.5005430651363, 17.30093799269207, 0.0))
DXFTag(code=210, value=(0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
DXFTag(code=40, value=0.4321803290912964)
DXFTag(code=41, value=2.392818306675625)
DXFTag(code=42, value=6.340229330820504)
DXFTag(code=1001, value=u'DCO15')
DXFTag(code=1071, value=2)
DXFTag(code=1071, value=2)
DXFTag(code=1000, value=u'pipelineconnection1')
DXFTag(code=1004, value=u'02000000')
DXFTag(code=1071, value=1)
DXFTag(code=1000, value=u'pipelineconnection1')
DXFTag(code=1004, value=u'01000000')
```

As I understand I need to *SET* 3 tags in each entity I want to connect to dbase. These are:

1. 1071 - the ordinal number of connection element.
2. 1000 - ASCII string (up to 255 bytes long) in extended data. (`'pipelineconnection1'` in my case)
3. 1004 - Chunk of bytes (up to 127 bytes long) in extended data. (primary key or connectoin filed number in hex)

But I can't use *set* methods to these kind of tags:

```
set_dxf_attrib(1071, 3)
set_dxf_attrib(1000, 'pipelineconnection1')
set_dxf_attrib(1004, hex(123))
```

This gives me an error: ***AttributeError: 1000***
I can set only tags in the `Valid_tag_list` e.g. `set_dxf_attrib('layer', 'my_layer')`.

How can I set tag by it's code not the name?
Are there any other methods to connect attribute table to DXF entity using python?

Documentation: [ezdxf](https://pythonhosted.org/ezdxf/entities.html) , [dxf specification](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf)